# Displaying Gradient in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

We're having trouble displaying gradients properly in IE. The following HTML displays the gradient well in Chrome and other browsers, but displays almost plain blue in IE. Would appreciate help!

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <STYLE type="text/css">
            body {
                /* Old browsers */
                background: #1e5799;
                /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
                background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzFlNTc5OSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjI0JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZmZmZmZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjcyJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZmZmZmZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiM3ZGI5ZTgiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
                /* FF3.6+ */
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #ffffff 24%, #ffffff 72%, #7db9e8 100%);
                 /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(24%,#ffffff), color-stop(72%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8));
                /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#ffffff 24%,#ffffff 72%,#7db9e8 100%); 
                /* Opera 11.10+ */
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#ffffff 24%,#ffffff 72%,#7db9e8 100%);
                /* IE10+ */
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#ffffff 24%,#ffffff 72%,#7db9e8 100%);
                /* W3C */
                background: linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#ffffff 24%,#ffffff 72%,#7db9e8 100%);
                /* IE6-8 */
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 );
            }
        </style>
    </HEAD>
<BODY>
    <H1 >Testing Blue Gradient</H1>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
  background-color: #1e5799;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1e5799), to(#7db9e8)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799, #7db9e8); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799, #7db9e8); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799, #7db9e8); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799, #7db9e8); 
  background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #1e5799, #7db9e8);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#1e5799', EndColorStr='#7db9e8'); 
}
```

I've tested it in IE 6-9 - works fine.

[***CSS3 Please***](http://css3please.com/)

Comment: Just a note to say the MS syntax is now incorrect. The final version of IE10 uses the latest syntax for CSS gradients, and doesn’t require a prefix.

The ms prefixed version should be removed, and the W3C version should be updated to:

       background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799, #7db9e8);

Notice the “to bottom” rather than top. The directions have flipped in the latest syntax, and require the to keyword preceding it.

Answer (score 0):

@zoltan has an excellent answer on how to do css.  Another approach instead of using filters would be to use http://css3pie.com/.  In addation to gradients, it also adds rounded corners and box shadows.  Plus it will let you do all three on the same element.

```
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for IE:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff'); 
/* for IE */
```